# Keras error with captured frames when calling predict with frames from game

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using SerpentAI library to capture a game frame, build a frame stack and feed it to Keras library for predict function.
When doing this, value error occurs

Here's me creating a frame stack:

```
full_game_frame = FrameGrabber.get_frames(
    [0],
    frame_shape=(960, 600),
    frame_type="PIPELINE"
).frames[0]

self.dqn_direction.build_frame_stack(full_game_frame.frame)
```

Build frame stack function:

```
def build_frame_stack(self, game_frame):
    frame_stack = np.stack((
        game_frame,
        game_frame,
        game_frame,
        game_frame
    ), axis=2)

self.frame_stack = frame_stack.reshape((1,) + frame_stack.shape)
```

The error says:

```
File "a:\anaconda\envs\serpent2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1695, in predict
    check_batch_axis=False)
  File "a:\anaconda\envs\serpent2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 132, in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))
ValueError: Error when checking : expected input_2 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 600, 960, 4, 3)
```

I assumed cutting off one array dimention from stack will help, but it raised another error

```
ValueError: Error when checking: expected input_2 to have shape (None, 960, 600, 4) but got array with shape (1, 600, 960, 4)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Also, getting the frame like this doesn't work:

```
# full_game_frame = game_frame
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have a problem in your dimensions. As the Error says the expected input is of shape (None, 960, 600, 4) whereas you try to pass an array with shape (1, 600, 960, 4).

Switching dimensions 1 and 2 (basically just a rotation of the image) should remove the error.

Additionally I don't see the necessity of stacking the image 4 times. Your first Error says your dimensions are (1,600,960,4,3) which means you have a RGB-Image at each position. I'm assuming the net takes a RGBA-Image as input. Instead of stacking the frame 4 times, try adding just one dimension to the frame with only ones (alpha channel). This should give you an image with shape (960, 600, 4).

Comment: The stacking was implemented inside Serpent AI. I was not able to remove stacking due to my lacking knowledge

I switched dimensions using np.swapaxes and it seems to pass through those lines of code. I'm checking another errors, but seems like switching dimensions is what i needed, thanks!